# To remove & between input type=text in HTML

Tags: html, email

Here is simple form which collects a user's info and sends that info to a specified email address. But whenever I am extracting those info into mail `&` appears between inputs. Like

```
email=some%40gmail.com&password=asdf&password-repeat=asdf
```

How can I remove this? Please help

Here is my HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="mailto:somebody@gmail.com">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

    <label for="password-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password-repeat" required>
    <hr>
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1) Add `enctype="text/plain"` to your `<form>` tag, e.g.:

```
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="mailto:alice@example.com">
```

2) Add `formenctype="text/plain"` to your `<button>` tag, e.g.:

```
<button type="submit" formenctype="text/plain" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
```

Both approaches will produce a body like:

```
email=bob@example.com
password=asdf
password-repeat=asdf
```

This is necessary because the default MIME type for the form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can read more on this at Mozilla.org. I've quoted `enctype` below but provided links for both.

> **enctype**
>
> When the value of the method attribute is post, enctype is the MIME type of content that is used to submit the form to the server. Possible values are:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: The default value if the attribute is not specified.
> - `multipart/form-data`: The value used for an `<input>` element with the type attribute set to "file".
> - `text/plain` (HTML5)
>
> This value can be overridden by a [formenctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formenctype) attribute on a `<button>` or `<input>` element.

- Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype
- Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formenctype

Here's your code (with demo email address) as a running example with `enctype`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="mailto:alice@example.com">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

    <label for="password-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password-repeat" required>
    <hr>
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it worked. I upvoted your question because it's a nice way to use `mailto`. You might consider anonymizing your email addresses in your post.

Comment: one more help needed :

Comment: email=bob@example.com
password=asdf
password-repeat=asdf 

in the above output how can i get ":" (colon) instead of (=)equals .

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this short of having the code updated in the browser or mail clients you're interested in because the data is being passed by the browser to the mail client. For reference, here's a discussion on Chromium handling of text/plain: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73979